# small music player for a single file

Tags: software-recommendation, music-player

Some time ago I saw a music player on ubuntu, which was looks like the embedded player on android phones: small popup window with progress bar and play/stop button, showing with a click on the music file.

Probably it was a feature of the player with an extended interface or just a dream? 
I browsed lots of players and still didn't find this one.

Comment: 'small popup window' as with the notification system? Which Ubuntu version/flavour it was? - I actually recommend the Lollypop music player (https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Lollypop)

Comment: not notification, but like this: 

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jC4Yh.png
 
it was ubuntu 12.04 or similar...